# Is it true that you have to say "astagafirullah" 100x times for him to accept ones forgivenes?

Tags: tawba

I read someone said it is & it was my first time ive known it, but i still have doubts about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not true.  You can ask for forgiveness once and that can be good enough.

There's no specific number mentioned.  May be the person who told you about the 100 times a day thing mixed it with a *hadith* of the Prophet =

> "A cloudiness comes over my heart, I seek forgiveness from Allah a
>   hundred times a day."

[[Sahih Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/muslim/48/52)